# Does "dodging a silver bullet" convey the meaning

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Assuming a dialogue like this

```
- (Bob)   How is the meeting going?
- (Alice) Dodging a silver bullet.
```

The idea that Alice is trying to express is that the customer is looking for a metaphorical "silver bullet" solution whereas Alice is trying to explain that this isn't possible and instead is trying to offer a realistic solution.

Does "dodging a silver bullet" convey such meaning and how easy is it to interpret the phrase right (in the right context)?

Comment: No; this involves a mixed metaphor which hasn't a clear meaning here. At face value, I'd take it to mean that she herself is trying to avoid taking on a suggested and apparently marvellous proposed solution to a problem for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't interpret that dialogue as your intended meaning at all. It seems to imply that there is some kind of magically effective solution, that Alice has been targeted with it, and that she has somehow evaded it - it suggests that Alice herself has dodged a silver bullet. It certainly doesn't imply that there *is no* silver bullet - how can one dodge something that doesn't exist?

"Dodging a silver bullet" is an unusual phrase, but could feasibly be applied to something like a antibiotic-resistant bacterium - it evades the usual, highly effective solution that has been applied successfully many times before. Even this seems like a somewhat strained phrasal portmanteau of "silver bullet" and "dodge a bullet", though.

Comment: It's a nice, clear meaning, though, and I don't doubt that in the right contexts, it would be understood precisely as described in the OP. But "silver bullet" is already a narrative metaphor, so adding a new verb _dodging_, certainly opens up the possibilities. _Tonto got his job by dodging a silver bullet._

Comment: Since it is commonly understood that "silver bullets" do not exist, wouldn't such a phrase actually mean something along the lines of "I am being offered something that is totally unrealistic (utter nonsense) and I try hard to avoid being pulled into this"?

Comment: @peterrogov A silver bullet is simply a solution that very effectively solves a wide range of problems - they're hard to come by, but silver bullets are not categorically non-existent. Penicillin was considered a silver bullet for many years, since it's so widely effective. You'd generally be correct to be skeptical of a silver bullet, but to suggest that all purported silver bullets are actually just nonsense goes too far.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie thanks and agreed. Perhaps I am being too radical stating that a silver bullet can not exist. In my case, it is sufficient to assume that the likelihood of its existence is quite low and therefore any solution that looks like a silver bullet must be taken with a pinch of salt.

Comment: There are bullets you fire and bullets others fire at you. A silver bullet is one you fire.